# Error(357,1): PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm writing simple Oracle function which returns output. I have a error in this line:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LINE);

Error(357,1): PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE' must be declared
```

Looks like there is no permission I tried to give all privileges to the user that I'm using.

Can you give me some advice how to fix the problem?

Comment: grant execute on DBMS_OUTPUT to username;

Comment: What is type of `LINE`? Can you show more code?

Comment: It's declared LINE CLOB;

Comment: I can't try right now on my system. Try to output `VARCHAR2` value. As I remember, in a case of wrong type there have to be another error, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It'll implicitly convert a CLOB to a `varchar2`, as long as it isn't too big ([as here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37638)); but if it is you'd get a different error, yes. Invalid identifier means it doesn't understand `dbms_output`, rather than a problem with the procedure within that package. So it seems likely it's surrounding code that's leading to the error, or a permissions problem; unusual to have lost the privileges though.

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Oracle 11g express edition

Answer (score 1):

You have non-ANSI letter in the name "DBMS_OUTPUT". According to your name I bet on russian letters 'ВМОТР'.

Comment: If he has copypasted the message then the letters is ok, i've checked